# Query for light color never hit the api endpoint

Tags: colors, actions-on-google

Problem: the query of color never hits the web endpoint.

Discovery of related light:

```
{
    "requestId": "9693057599391372733",
    "payload": {
        "agentUserId": "xxx",
        "devices": [{
            "id": "yyy",
            "type": "action.devices.types.LIGHT",
            "traits": ["action.devices.traits.OnOff", "action.devices.traits.Brightness", "action.devices.traits.ColorSpectrum"],
            "name": {
                "name": "front door light"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "attributes": {},
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "Zinno"
            },
            "customData": {}
        }]
    }
}
```

Simulation to query for color light

[image: simulation to get color light]

My endpoint API never gets the request for this query. What can cause this?

Comment: Have you followed all the steps to link your account to the Google Assistant? https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app Additionally you can't ask the color of a light right now, but you can ask if it's on or off.

Comment: The turn on/off just work, but the query for light color does not (describe above).This is because of this query is not working from google assistant side?

Comment: Yes you can query if the light is on or off, but you cannot query the light color. The Google Assistant does not support that type of query.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.
I think the doc https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/colorspectrum  needs edit in section "Sample QUERY Request and Response"

Comment: Perhaps, although when this does become possible the response you're sending will already be useful. Don't remove the color in your response.